# Not able to create react app, wired error?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npx

I am using the following cmnd to initialize a new react project:
`npx create-react-app test`
But I get this error :

```
Invalid "exports" main target "index.js" defined in the package config /usr/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/is-promise/package.json
```

I tried : 
1. clear the cache using 
`npm cache clean --force`
2.updating npm to 6.14.4
3. installing it globally `npm install create-react-app -g`

Comment: All of a sudden I started getting this error just now

Comment: Are you on Windows or Mac?

Comment: I am using arch linux

Comment: What node version do you have installed?

Comment: node version v13.13.0

Comment: I suggest you always use the version that is labeled "Recommended for most users". That version is currently at 12.16.2.

Comment: Can you try these [steps to create a react project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62122386/2873538)?

Answer (score 2):

Following [this tread](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8896) I got the idea, that you need to downgrade the node version to 12.12.0 and error will disappear

**Edit:** As for now, this bug is fixed in 2.2.2 version of is-promise package. If you still experience problems creating new CRA, consider `npm install -g --force create-react-app`

If even then bug is still present, please comment your issue to this github [issue](https://github.com/then/is-promise/issues/20)

Comment: I really cannot tell if this helped, since I have another error now: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'

Answer (score 1):

Try to complete uninstall node js by using revo uninstaller  or  delete AppData\Roaming\npm folder . I hope its will be working fine . Also dont forgot to use latest version of node js .

Comment: thank you, but this did not work for me, now I have another err : ```internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:

Comment: you have to completely uninstall node js and reinstall this or try to use another machine .

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently the issue is from npm and non of us has done anything wrong, still we can use Yarn to start a new react project while they solve it, follow the steps:

step 1: `yarn init -y`

step 2: Insert this to package.json

```
"resolutions": {
    "is-promise": "2.1.0",
    "run-async/is-promise": "2.1.0"
  }
```

step 3: `yarn add --dev create-react-app`

step 4: `yarn create-react-app ../my-app`

Answer (score 0):

There is an error with latest create-react-app version 3.4.1

To proceed while while this is getting fixed, I was able to create a new react project with the previous version of create-react-app 3.4.0

To do this first, please remove create-react-app if you installed it globally

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

Once globally uninstalled you can use npx to create a new project

```
npx create-react-app@3.4.0 yourProjectName
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following exact command: 
Exact: `npx react-create-app test` , Your code is incorrect because react must precede create: npx **create-react**-app test